# If A and B are nonzero matrices such that det( A )and det( B )are nonzero, can AB be the zero matrix?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Can someone help me aproch the problem.

I know that for this to work a1d1 can not equal b1c1 as well as a2d2 can not equal b2c2. But am utterly stuck on what do next.

Comment: Hint: What is $det(AB)$?

Comment: $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$

Comment: In which ring are you working? Does it have zero divisors ?

Comment: Thanks for this help. I was wondering is  det(AB)=det(A)det(B) something I should prove? This is not provided in my textbook.

Comment: @James A textbook that does not tell you that is a pretty bad textbook...

Answer (score 2):

If $\operatorname{det}A\neq 0$ we know that $A^{-1}$ exists. If $AB=0$, multiplying by $A^{-1}$ to the left we get $B=0$.

Another way to get there is to note that $0=\operatorname{det}(AB)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B)$